# Kivy - Cannot keep focus in TextInput after submiting, Enter key does not confirm it

Tags: python, kivy

So i manage to get focus in the TextInput > tracknumb. at start of the app, but still when i confirm the input, finally i can do it with enter now too, but it looses the focus from textinput once i submit it.
Can you please advice what am I missing?

[Whole Code here](https://pastebin.com/WugUfG2j)

```
import kivy
import kivy
import mysql.connector
from datetime import datetime
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock

Window.size = (480, 800)

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.cols = 1  # Set columns for main layout
        self.inside = GridLayout(cols=2, row_force_default=True,
                                 row_default_height=50, padding=20,
                                 spacing=10)  # Create a new grid layout
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Tracking Number \n Checker", halign="center", font_size=40))  # Top Label
        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text="Work Number:", halign="center", font_size=20))  # Add a label widget
        self.worknumb = TextInput(text_validate_unfocus=True, multiline=False, font_size=20, halign="center")
        self.inside.add_widget(self.worknumb)
        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text="Tracking \nNO. Scan:", halign="center", font_size=20))
        self.tracknumb = TextInput(multiline=False, font_size=15, halign="center")  # Create a Text input box stored in the name variable
        self.inside.add_widget(self.tracknumb)  # Add the text input widget to the GUI

        self.add_widget(self.inside)  # Add the interior layout to the main
        self.submit = Button(text="Submit", font_size=40, size_hint =(.5, .5))  # Submit button
        self.add_widget(self.submit)
        self.submit.bind(on_press=self.send_tracknumb)
        self.resultbox = Image(source="status.png")  #image box on bottom
        self.add_widget(self.resultbox)

        Window.bind(on_key_down=self.pressed)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.focus_tracknumb, 1)
    def pressed(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode == 40 or keycode == 13:
            self.send_tracknumb(None)

    def focus_tracknumb(self, _):
        self.tracknumb.focus = True
    def send_tracknumb(self, _):
        tracknumb = self.tracknumb.text
        worknumb = self.worknumb.text
        errorsound = SoundLoader.load("incorrect.mp3")  # add sound to the scanning
        correctsound = SoundLoader.load("correct.ogg")
        self.tracknumb.text = ""  # Reset text to blank in each text input
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can change focus back to the `TextInput` in the `pressed()` method:

```
def pressed(self, instance):
    tracknumb = self.tracknumb.text
    worknumb = self.worknumb.text
    errorsound = SoundLoader.load("incorrect.mp3") #add sound to the scanning
    correctsound = SoundLoader.load("correct.ogg")
    self.tracknumb.text = "" # Reset text to blank in each text input
    self.tracknumb.focus = True  # Change focus back to tracknumb
```

Comment: that one did not help, but I finally manage to get the Enter key working, and it has focus on beggining of the app which is not very usefull but after submition it will looses focus again.

Answer (score 0):

Och dong, I missed it :D it was so simple, I had to put the function to that part

```
def send_tracknumb(self, _):
```

I missed that one in all the text :{

```
Clock.schedule_once(self.focus_tracknumb, 0.1)
```